# Is it possible to create a invite link of a server using the guild id in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command through which i can get the server invite link by entering the guilds id.
Like

```
@bot.command()
async def createinvitelink(ctx,guildid):
   pass
```

so whenever someone uses the command they have to enter any guild id where the bot is. And the bot will give the invite link to the user of that server.
So far i had wrote this code but it doen't works.

```
@client.command(name='dm')
async def dm(ctx, guild_id: int):
    if ctx.author.id == owner:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
        guildchannel = guild.system_channel
        invitelink = await guildchannel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
        await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

Can someone help me how can i do that?

Comment: Additional information about what you mean by "So far i had wrote this code but it doesn't work." will help. What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that system_channel can be None sometimes. So just get 1st channel from the server's channels and create its invite.

```py
@client.command(name='dm')
async def _dm(ctx, guild_id: int):
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    channel = guild.channels[0]
    invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1)
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. I was having trouble with that but didn't knew it was that ez. Thank you so much, Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def createinvite(ctx, guildid: int):
  try:
    guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
    invitelink = ""
    i = 0
    while invitelink == "":
      channel = guild.text_channels[i]
      link = await channel.create_invite(max_age=300,max_uses=1)
      invitelink = str(link)
      i += 1
    await ctx.send(invitelink)
  except Exception:
    await ctx.send("Something went wrong")
```

I guess I have to explain that don't I...let's see

We first receive the Guild ID and type hint it to integer coz we don't want a string
Then I created a blank string for the invite link and a random variable with its value set to 0
Then we run a while loop and why we are doing is because it is not necessary that your bot will have invite perms for the first channel in the server, so what we want is that if the bot does not get the invite for the first channel, it tries the next, and the next till it has checked every channel in the server. Only then can you say that your bot can't get an invite to the server
Anyways, so we check the text channels and set the value of our invitelink variable to whatever string output we get. This will go on till the bot actually finds an invite. If it doesn't we get an exception